# How can I show a standard toast regardless of where the user is?

Tags: android, android-toast

Im trying to show a toast, but the toast requires me to target a context.

How can I target "system" or "anywhere"?

I want to show a toast when the user's clipboard has been updated from my app, so the end user knows when he is ready to paste.

Guess I need a permission to be able to show a toast anywhere?

Im talking about these:
[image: toast]

And I want to show one even if the user is for example in a web browser waiting for the clipboard to get updated or are not currently using my app. So I need to get tge context the user currently is at.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, but if your app is updating the clipboard, you can use the same `Context` you're using to get the `ClipboardManager`. You don't need any special permission for a `Toast`.

Comment: So "when the user's clipboard has been updated from my app" isn't really what you mean?

Comment: @MikeM: What I meant, is that when I have updated the clipboard from my app, I want to just tell the user "Now its ready, you can paste now if you want". Else the user might try to paste, and then get the "old" text because the process in question is not done yet. Eg, user clicks on a link, my app does a process that can take a few seconds, and the result is stored in clipboard. The user the pastes this result in a form. To tell the user that the user has finished waiting these "a few seconds" that can vary depending on how loaded the device is, I want to just show a Toast that its ready.

Comment: Oh, so that is what you meant. Then there's really no problem. You can show a `Toast` from pretty much anywhere you have access to a `Context`, which doesn't need to be any other than your app's own. Just issue the `Toast` after you set the clipboard data. It will show on top of whatever app is currently in the foreground.

Comment: @MikeM: Tried with getApplicationContext() but that didnt work. The code is:                 Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Authentication is done, select paste on the OTP field.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
                android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());

Comment: Don't kill the process. Why are you doing that? And just use the `Context` you're in. You don't need to get the `Application`'s.

Comment: The process needs to be killed because if the process is running when the process is retriggered a second time (even if its done with whatever it needs to do), it wont process again. So if the process is done with whatever it should do, I must kill it. Also saves on memory consumtion since theres no need to have it running in background when its done. How I get the context the user is currently is in? For example the web browser or whatever?

Comment: No, the process does not need to be killed; you just need to handle your `Service` correctly. That's most likely why your `Toast` isn't showing. Furthermore, you can't get another app's active `Context`, and it wouldn't help your situation anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getActivity()` as your context like this :

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "this is my Toast message!!! =)",  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try getApplicationContext()

Eg. if you are running a service, you can try something like

```
MyService.this.getApplicationContext()
```

This should provide context when app is not visible.

Comment: Do I need to run a service for this? My application just runs hidden (without a visible UserActivity) a few seconds, and then posts the result to clipboard, and then hard-kills itself. But I should try your suggestion, it might work anyways.

Comment: Didn't work. MyService became red and trying with just "this.getApplicationContext()" didnt work.

Comment: MyService was just an example name if you are running a service. If app is hidden, how is it working? Inside an activity?
My assumption was if app is in background, it is interacting through a service? Some code snippet may be useful!

Comment: The application registers a URL-handler, where it also gets its input. Upon getting a call on the URL handler, It then starts a empty mainactivity (shown as a white flash screen), does its processing, and then exits. Before it exits I want to show a simple toast - that SURVIVIES the app killing itself - that the user may paste now.

Comment: If your app exists, the toast will still be visible on whatever screen is available. Ofcourse if a click happens on the screen, toast will disappear. You can originate your toast from main activity itself just before killing it.